# How do I prove or disprove that this function is Ω(n^1.5)?

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

so I have this recursive function:
T(n) = T(log(n)) + T(n-log(n)) + n

I've tried many times solving it, but I just wasn't successful. (finding the Theta)
Basically it's enough for me to prove or disprove if it's Omega of n^1,5 (Ω(n^1.5))

Help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

> tl;dr:
>
> given T(n) = T(log(n)) + T(n-log(n)) + n
>
> prove or disprove: T(n) = Ω(n^1.5)

Comment: It’s likely being down voted because there’s no demonstrated effort on your part to solve the problem.

Comment: I've been googling and stackoverflowing the question for 2 days now. There's simply nothing similar to this one.
There's plenty of examples that use constants such as: T(n) = T(n/4) + T(3n/4) + n. But none that use FUNCTIONS in the call itself. It's harder to analyze functions that eventually have something to do with (log(n-log(n-log(n-log))) (and so on)

Comment: Looks like a better fit for cs.SE.

Comment: @JeroenMostert whats that?

Comment: SE is Stack Exchange, so cs.SE is cs.stackexchange.com, one of our sister communities.

Comment: @JeroenMostert oh that's cool! Thanks. What's the difference? I mean how should I know whether to post this here or there?

Comment: There's no hard and fast rules; there's overlap between lots of communities and many questions could fit in more than one (but should still only be asked in one). Basically, look at the tour page and the questions typically asked (and upvoted/answered) in a community to see where it fits. This question, while it does deal with programming, is a bit more theoretical than most on SO and seems to fit cs.SE better. Disclaimer: I'm not a regular visitor of cs.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `T(n)` doesn't suddenly become negative at some value of `n`, we can give a lower bound for the left hand side if we neglect the first term:

[image]

We define a new function `S(n)` such that:

[image]

We can immediately see that it has [image] terms (ignoring off-by-one etc.). Thus if we keep expanding:

[image]

At this stage, since we know that `log(n) << n` for any large `n`, we can apply a Taylor expansion to the third term in the recursive call to `S(n)`:

[image]

We can realistically ignore the 2nd term too. Applying this approximation to every `S(n)` call:

[image]

Now, we know that:

[image]

`b` obviously can be 1.5; therefore:

[image]

---

EDIT: some numerical tests to confirm this result -

Code:

```
uint64_t T(int n) {
  return n <= 1 ? 0 : T(n - log(n)) + T(log(n)) + (uint64_t)n;
}
```

Results:

```
N           T(N)
--------------------------
2           2
4           6
8           18
16          60
32          181
64          578
128         1911
256         6331
512         22011
1024        79304
2048        279719
4096        1016217
8192        3814210
16384       13902832
32768       51540129
65536       195366441
131072      732435510
262144      2744988819
524288      10457580914
1048576     39910628826
```

Plot of `N^2/log(N)` against `T(N)`:

[image]

The relationship is linear, meaning that

[image]

... confirming the given result.

Comment: Very minor formatting note: `\text{LHS}` (or `\mathit` if you want italics) prevents issues with spacing, as plain `LHS` in math mode is formatted as a multiplicative expression (giving the weird-looking spacing between `LH` and `S`). Otherwise, kudos for doing math on StackOverflow by inlining pictures, that can't be convenient. (Another reason why this is a better question for cs.SE.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert ah thanks for the tip; that issue was really triggering my OCD.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @Elie: I think you want to thank meowgoesthedog, I hardly did anything.

Comment: You're right, I mistakenly typed your name in. Thanks a bunch @meowgoesthedog